# How to merge subsequences with a closed form to a universal closed form?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $f_1:\mathbb{N}_{odd} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$f_1(n) = a_1 + b_1 \cdot c_1^n$$

and $f_2:\mathbb{N}_{even} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$f_2(n) = a_2 + b_2 \cdot c_2^n$$

Is it possible to find a general formula $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ that fits both even and odd $n$?

Comment: Why even bother? The split closed form is clear enough, and any further merging will give complication. But, if you insist, try $\dfrac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}$ and $\dfrac{1 - (-1)^n}{2}$.